# Use net start in Windows service recovery

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, services

I am setting up service recovery, and am having issues getting any 'run program' command line parameter to work. I've tried these so far:

```
SC failure MSSQL$TEST reset= 2 command= "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe net start mssql$test" actions= run/1000/run/1000/run/1000
SC failure MSSQL$TEST reset= 2 command= "C:\Windows\System32\sc.exe sc Start mssql$test" actions= run/1000/run/1000/run/1000
SC failure MSSQL$TEST reset= 2 command= "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe sc start MSSQL$test" actions= run/1000/run/1000/run/1000
```

None of these restarts the service. I set all three attempts to run, to keep the service from restarting normally. 
All these commands work in `CMD` by hand, but I cannot get them to work through the services recovery tab.

I am killing the service using `taskkill /f /pid ###`,
and I am on Windows 10 Pro x64.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried putting ``/c`` between ``cmd.exe`` and the command?

Comment: And, alternatively, doing `sc.exe Start …`, without the extra `sc` in between?

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

This is OP. I managed to post as a guest, I apologize. I have not tried adding /c yet. wouldn't that just set the command line parameter to '/C NET START SERVICENAME'?

Scott's answer of removing SC from SC start in:

```
 SC failure MSSQL$TEST reset= 2 command= "C:\Windows\System32\sc.exe sc Start mssql$test" actions= run/1000/run/1000/run/1000
```

resolved the issue. I believe this is because it was attempting to call the .exe from withing itself, causing the error.

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Comment: Yeah, I posted m answer in hopes of sciiching the conversation here, Ill merge those now, thank you very mich